# Obtain groups only in regex

Tags: regex

Hello Im trying to get only time groups such as (these 3 strings):

```
'6 hrs'
'16 mins'
'5 hrs 30 mins'
```

From text

```
6 hrs blah blah  16 mins blah
blah  5 hrs 30 mins xyz
```

I tried with this `/(\d+ hrs)?( \d+ mins)?/gm` ,
but I get 32 matches instead. Please see this https://regex101.com/r/xmoMKz/4

How to get only the groups I want? Without the other matches - I even dont know what are the other matches, positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get rid of the capturing groups with `?:`, you should be able to get what you want. And rather than have both subgroups be optional, it’s better to make the first one not optional and just check for either `hrs` or `mins`. So try:

```
(?:\d+ (?:hrs|mins))(?: \d+ mins)?
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/nQbrb0/1